KeyError: 'Name' in pipenv/vendor/importlib_metadata/_adapters.py:54 using pipenv
I got this weird error in my CI/CD pipeline running in GCP Cloud build.

Package installation failed... KeyError: 'Name' site-packages/pipenv/vendor/importlib_metadata/_adapters.py:54 everything is working locally when runnning pipenv install.

I'm running in python 3.11.4.
Troubleshooting steps that I have followed are:

Remove the Pipfile.lock entirely and run again pipenv install didn't work.
Removed the environment entirely pipenv --rm and removed the cache pip cache purge then recreate again the env pipenv shell && pipenv install didn't solved the issue.

Still more on it:

I found this thread: https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/1125#issuecomment-2191295673 where the issue is identified as caused by a breaking change in importlib_metadata==8.0.0 and that the way of solving it is just pin the version importlib-metadata==7.2.1 so I went ahead and applied the change but unfortunately it didn't solved the issue.
I ran as well pipenv graph | grep "importlib" and all the dependencies for importlib are pointing to that 7.2.1 version.


After running and validating that the build was working properly in docker by using:
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm64 -t fakename -f Dockerfile .

I found that pipenv was resolving the dependencies correctly by building the image properly all along the way. Then I found that I had this setting in kaniko:
--cache=true

Then I disabled it by setting --cache=false and it worked and solved the issue, this will slow down the builds unfortunately but I had no options for now.
I explored and tested other options for example:

Do not shout down the cache entirely and instead use cache-ttl:

--cache=true
--cache-ttl=24h

And it worked the first time but after a while maybe 2 hours later it lead me to the same issue so I rolled back the changes unfortunately.

I found --cache-repo setting and this give me the following combination:

--cache=true
--cache-ttl=24h
--cache-repo=myrepo

Maybe that will avoid other cache repos to overwrite my dependencies' cached in this repo and will give me the granularity that I need for the cache(I have not tested this yet).
